# Making a TypeScript function/'task' registry

Tags: typescript, caching, weakmap

I am trying to write a TypeScript class that functions as a Function/'Task' registry, such that it is simply a class with a `Record<string, Function>` static member within that stores that functions that are retrieved simply by the name of the function.

Here is my implementation:

```
export function RegisterTaskWith(taskRegistry: TaskRegistry) {
    return function (
        target: any,
        propertyKey: string,
        descriptor: PropertyDescriptor,
    ) {
        taskRegistry.registerTask(propertyKey, descriptor.value);
        taskRegistry.listTasks();
    };
}

export class TaskRegistry {
    private tasks: Record<string, () => Promise<void>> = {};

    registerTask(name: string, task: () => Promise<void>) {
        this.tasks[name] = task;
    }

    async executeTask(name: string) {
        const task = this.tasks[name];
        if (task) {
            await task();
        } else {
            throw new Error(`Task "${name}" not found in the registry.`);
        }
    }

    listTasks() {
        return Object.keys(this.tasks);
    }
}

const taskRegistry = new TaskRegistry();

class MyTasks {
    registeredTasks: string[] = [];

    @RegisterTaskWith(taskRegistry)
    async task1() {
        this.registeredTasks.push('task1'); # Line 1
        console.log('Task 1 executed.');
    }

    @RegisterTaskWith(taskRegistry)
    async task2() {
        this.registeredTasks.push('task2'); # Line 2
        console.log('Task 2 executed.');
    }
}

const myTasks = new MyTasks();
console.log('Registered Tasks:', taskRegistry.listTasks());
taskRegistry.executeTask('task1');
// this.registeredTasks.push('task1');
             ^
//TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'registeredTasks')
taskRegistry.executeTask('task2');
console.log("myTasks.registeredTasks: ", myTasks.registeredTasks)

// The main problem is that the `this` in Line 1 and Line 2 is not an instance of `MyTasks`.
```

The error that I encountered this is the `this` on Line 1 and Line 2 does not refer to the instance of `MyTasks` hence they have no access to `MyTasks.registeredTasks` member.

How can I make sure that an instance of it is also passed into the registry so that I can call the function by retrieving it from the registry and simply call it?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#code/EQVwzgpgBGAuBOBLAxrYAoAZiAdqxA9jlAEoQDmicE8AKgIZgDWA6orABYAUsjTZlOPACeALigNmAqgmEBKKAG90UVVHgRYIeMWx5YhYlxVrTveOU3j6OYQBoTp1QAd4BZzVjCA0hDEwERBxyByc1ABMIMGQkZ1gCeHEABTcPeC8AESiYxDiE0LUFZTDVXikKGREAOg1BWBpJJi5Xd08fPzsoSOjY%20PgqgDd6ABsQCDkAbkcnMv4KoWEq4ZlGsC5J6YBfKc30dGRhxjAJPmkFpWnXRCH6qFmwcTJkBPCAHiEgkKh1qABeAD4oCkCABbKgQV4DAiIcL-QG-JTbPamWoyBp8Lg4eggiDiD7BTqzcQ-AFAtxgyCQ6GworTMwcKhVe4AbSxOIAun87nwpqZdtNGMI8FAIAAPCDIED1RqY7G4gJIYK0kpQZ44ODc5hcziMllsiDs3klRCYb6zZUqtT0ADu9HYmqaGxVmxFw0gF0tak4bmtUBwEF9AFF4G54FwAAaNKDAAAkin1m2AfoIsCgmAIuHCUCCdw40FRCyq4adJV2fORamWcFWP2KJQ0Wh0UAA8gAjABWEtgVSYfjWOrATL4YBLql2-LVGtmZ1kXP9vsaM5E6ym%200OYGOAFlhKsPWoC-UNOFVnjAsFmZyERfV6YAAIz9HMNicHineayOQCsBC5AOgCMtZ0l6DKDgeNAQMew5VM44DcAA5LMf5waOTiTgQwwQEsBDkFwcFRn%20IripK9ThFUyFGmOFaqPe76Pqw7DcNO74iJ%20piCsKswAEyASqA41LRR6rNBsG4Vx5FAaoaEYVhOF4XwUCcYREpShBZEoeOeyTqmII7sOc4BlA241hsUmYcM2G4Q%20R4nMwDxwYSb51NUVawMZGxMU5ixisp0oYghfBIe5jmVF5REqTK-nMJx4mmTJXDADpQlgYJw7iMAnSJVByUQaschAA) (although it doesn't show the error but `registeredTasks` is empty at the end which shouldn't be the case).

Comment: Is the issue that you have a compiler error (in which case you probably work more to provide a [mre]) or that you have runtime issues (in which case you should probably remove references to the compiler error and or fix them)?  What's the focus of the question?

Answer (score 0):

When the `RegisterTaskWith` decorator calls the `registerTask` method, it passes in the `descriptor.value` (the method the decorator is attched to) as an argument. The function however doesn't keep it's context (more info about JS context from MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)). To keep the context, you would need to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) the function the `MyTasks` instance again. That is not possible, since you cannot access the class instance from the method decorator.

Just as a note - I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve, but using a class method with a different context is not common practise in TypeScript so the decorators aren't really made with this in mind. I would consider passing working with the whole class instance, as oposed to the individual methods.

So to answer your question directly: you simply cannot pass the instance to the registry using a decorator.

If you really need the beahviour you are describing, I would consider adding the tasks in the `MyTasks` construtor something like this:

```
"use strict"
function RegisterTaskWith(taskRegistry: TaskRegistry, name: string, task: () => Promise<void>, context: any) {
        taskRegistry.registerTask(name, task.bind(context));
        taskRegistry.listTasks();
}

class TaskRegistry {
    private tasks: Record<string, () => Promise<void>> = {};

    registerTask(name: string, task: () => Promise<void>) {
        this.tasks[name] = task;
    }

    async executeTask(name: string) {
        const task = this.tasks[name];
        if (task) {
            await task();
        } else {
            throw new Error(`Task "${name}" not found in the registry.`);
        }
    }

    listTasks() {
        return Object.keys(this.tasks);
    }
}

const taskRegistry = new TaskRegistry();

class MyTasks {
    registeredTasks: string[] = [];

    constructor() {
        RegisterTaskWith(taskRegistry, "task1", this.task1, this);
        RegisterTaskWith(taskRegistry, "task2", this.task2, this);    
    }

    async task1() {
        this.registeredTasks.push('task1');
        console.log('Task 1 executed.');
    }

    async task2() {
        this.registeredTasks.push('task2');
        console.log('Task 2 executed.');
    }
}

const myTasks = new MyTasks();
console.log('Registered Tasks:', taskRegistry.listTasks());
taskRegistry.executeTask('task1');
taskRegistry.executeTask('task2');
console.log("myTasks.registeredTasks: ", myTasks.registeredTasks)
```